# Writing to JSON file in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON file that is like this:

```
{
   "user" : { "movie": 0 } 
}
```

I want to add another user to the above JSON file. For example, something like this:

```
{   "user" : {
                "movie" : 0
            },
    "user2" : {
                "movie": 0
             }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a "command line argument that asks for user's name"? It is gibberish to me.

Comment: To be honest, I shouldn't even have mentioned that because I know that part, it'll just be something like `puts "Enter Username: "` `name = gets`. I just really want to know, how to add onto the JSON file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the file into a Ruby Hash using

```
hash = JSON.load(File.read("path/to/file"))
```

Then edit the Hash

```
hash["user2"] = { "movie" => 0 }
```

Then encode it back

```
File.write("path/to/file", JSON.dump(hash))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, definitely helped me out.

Comment: it is adding backslashes to the file